# Javascript not loading for users with Read permission

Tags: 2010, javascript, permissions

I got a Javascript on a Sharepoint 2010 site which is not loading for users with Read permissions. The Javascript is embedded in the site and users with Read permissions have access to it, but the Javascript is only loading with at least contribute permission.

Why am I experiencing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the script file(s) is/are checked in and published as major version.

The library may be set up so that site contributors can see unpublished files (minor versions), whereas users with read permissions can only see files that are published (major versions).

It's a common problem and easy to miss.

Comment: They are all checked in, but i cant publish them because i dont have right permissions. How can that be, i got Full Control permissions on the page.

I embedded the Javascript in the .aspx Page, which is checked in and able to publish. Now it works. Thank you very much, i overlooked this, because there is no publish option in the Designer (or at least i cant find it)