# Page Javascript Not Loading

Tags: list, javascript, permissions

**Information:**
To give you some background information on what I have done, I have created a SharePoint List that stores various columns of data that I use to create objects on a page.

I have a javascript file named **builder.js** whose location is **Site Assets > js > builder.js** This file is used to construct div objects from the List columns and append them to the page.

**Problem:**
The problem that I am having is that I can view the page normally, however, when a user with any permission under **contribute** tries to access the page, it will not render as it is suppose to.  I check within the developer tools and the builder.js file is not even loaded.

**Question:**
Is this a problem with the permission level for the users?  I would prefer not giving all users a **contribute** level permission just to see the page.

Is there something that I am overlooking?

---

Also, I am aware that a similar question has been asked before: [Javascript not loading for users with Read permission](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/104338/javascript-not-loading-for-users-with-read-permission). The problem with this, is the user ended up embedding the javascript withing the .aspx page, which is something I want to avoid at all cost and should be my last resort.

Comment: How do you load your builder.js file?

Comment: Did you check the permissions for SiteAssets ? Did you ask to a user to directly open the JS file into their browser to see if they can read it.

Comment: @DanielStölzner I just added the JavaScript with a script tag in the header of the page.

Comment: @AymKdn I will have to check that.